# Implicit Parametric Polymorpishm

Tags: programming-languages, parametric-polymorphism

What is implicit parametric polymorphism?

Explicit parametric polymorphism: generic parameters T

From Programming Language Pragmatics "In parametric polymorphism the code takes a type (or set of types) as a parameter, either explicitly or implicitly."

Is implicit parametric polymorphism when parameter type is not specified? Like in Python or JavaScript?

Comment: The answer to your question is: _No!_. Please see the Wikipedia article on [Parametric Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism)

Comment: @Apalala have you read it yourself? It says nothing about IMPLICIT parametric polymorphism.

Comment: "implicit" just means that the types are not specified in the program but rather inferred by the parser. Python is a language with dynamic typing (any object can be assigned to any name), yet programmers tend to types consistently for names. The MyPy project deduces and validates static types for Python projects based on use.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Java generics are an example "explicit parametric polymorphism" and "implicit parametric polymorphism" is when the types of the parameters are not specified, as found in Python. Please look at "Basic polymorphic typechecking", Luca Cardelli, 1987 - https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0167642387900190?ref=cra_js_challenge&fr=RR-1

Cardelli states, "In fact, in implicit polymorphism one can totally omit type information by interpreting the resulting programs as having type variables associated to parameters and identifiers. The programs then appear to be type-free, but rigorous type-checking can still be performed." This is a pretty good description of Python's approach.